# PHP: How to store session in cookie

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-variables, session-cookies

I am new to PHP and am currently struggling with the following:

**I have a login page where I start a session as below which works well so far.**

```
session_start();
// ...
$_SESSION["Customer"]["username"] = $username;
$_SESSION["Customer"]["email"] = $email;
```

Now I have never used sessions before but assume they die once a user closes their browser and I would like to keep them logged in so that they don't have to do this whenever they re-enter the page. 
My thought was to use a cookie for that but I am not sure how I can store my session in a cookie.

I did some research on this and came across the following but **I am not sure if that's the right approach and how to use it for what I need**.
Can someone help me with this ?

```
session_set_cookie_params ( int $lifetime [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]] );
```

`lifetime` in my case would be indefinite so as long as possible,
`path` would probably just be "/",
`secure` would be true
and I wouldn't need the `httponly`.

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In fact, php does store the session in a cookie - a single cookie, usually called `PHPSESSID`. This corresponds to a file (the filename of which is the value of the `PHPSESSID` cookie) on the server which is a set of key/value pairs, such as those you outline above.

Provided that the user has cookies enabled, sessions will work fine. The main thing to make sure is that every response uses `session_start()`; otherwise you won't be able to access values within `$_SESSION`.

If you want this session cookie to stick around after the browser closes, you need to use `session_set_cookie_params()` ([documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)) which you would call before `session_start()`.

I'd definitely recommend against the approach of 'eternal' sessions, just from a scalability point of view - bearing in mind each session corresponds to a file on the server these could build up after a while (especially if you are a high traffic website).

There is one approach which involves storing a separate cookie on the user's browser, containing login information which your website can look for within `$_COOKIE`, enabling an 'auto-login' process, which you could explore. I'm not sure it's the most secure approach though.

Hope that helps a little.

Comment: Thanks a lot - this is really helpful ! I agree that eternal sessions might be wrong but then using the above I could just set their lifetime to say a month or so, right ? Also, all my pages start with session_start(); so that should be covered. Now if I would like to use the above I would just put the session_set_cookie_params.. after setting my session variables ? Reading through your answer it sounds like the separate cookie might be the better alternative. What would you suggest ?

Comment: Personally I would use `session_set_cookie_params`, which you'd put before `session_start()`. Storing a separate cookie with login information feels a bit messy - just because the storing of user passwords openly in a cookie is not very good practice.

Comment: Thanks for that ! I agree. I start all my pages with session_start() but setting the session variables happens somewhere in the middle of my code (i.e. when a user logs in successfully). So if the session_set_cookie_params needs to happen before session_start() would I do that in my includes file that includes the session_start() on all pages ?